# Python: Unify multiple lists into one

Tags: python

Could you help me with the following challenge I am currently facing:

I have multiple lists, each of which contains multiple strings. Each string has the following format:

"ID-Type" - where ID is a number and type is a common Python type. One such example can be found here:

```
["1-int", "2-double", "1-string", "5-list", "5-int"],
["3-string", "1-int", "1-double", "5-double", "5-string"]
```

Before calculating further, I now want to preprocess these list to unify them the following way:

- Count how often each type is appearing in each list
- Generate a new list, combining both results
- Create a mapping from initial list to that new list

As an example

In the above lists, we have the following types:

List 1: 2 int, 1 double, 1 string, 1 list

List 2: 2 string, 2 double, 1 int

The resulting table should now contain:
2 int, 2 double, 2 string, 1 list (in order to be able to contain both lists), like this:

```
[
"int_1-int", 
"int_2-int", 
"double_1-double", 
"double_2-double", 
"string_1-string", 
"string_2-string", 
"list_1-list"
]
```

And lastly, in order to map input to output, the idea is to have a corresponding dictionary to map this transformation, e.g., for list_1:

```
{
"1-int": "int_1-int", 
"2-double": "double_1-double", 
"1-string": "string_1-string", 
"5-list": "list_1-list", 
"5-int": "int_2-int"
}
```

I want to prevent to do this with a nested loop and multiple iterations - are there any libraries or is there maybe a smart vectorized solution to address this challenge?

Comment: So you want to create both: a combined list **and** a dictionary?

Comment: instead of having the first list with a id number and type jammed together into a single strrig, using a tuple here would be cleaner - it means you can get to the type without processing the string every time. Even better - the tuple can still be used as the key in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Just add them:
Example :

`['it'] + ['was'] + ['annoying']`

You should read the Python tutorial to learn basic info like this.

Just another method....

```
import itertools
ab = itertools.chain(['it'], ['was'], ['annoying'])
list(ab)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is what you want to do:

To make a joint list:

```py
['any item'] + ['any item 2']
```

If you want to turn the list into a dictionary:

```py
dict(zip(['key 1', 'key 2'], ['value 1', 'value 2']))
```

Another method of joining 2 lists:

```py
a = ['list item', 'another list item']
a.extend(['another list item', 'another list item'])
```

Comment: Also, all of this is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=lists).

Answer (score 0):

Just add them: Example :

`['it'] + ['was'] + ['annoying']`

You should read the Python tutorial to learn basic info like this.

Just another method....

```
import itertools
ab = itertools.chain(['it'], ['was'], ['annoying'])
list(ab)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, this approach doesn't really make sense unless you specifically need to have the items in the resulting list and dict in this exact format.  But here's how you can do it:

```
def process_type_list(type_list):
    mapping = dict()
    for i in type_list:
        i_type = i.split('-')[1]
        n_occur = 1
        map_val = f'{i_type}_{n_occur}-{i_type}'
        while map_val in mapping.values():
            n_occur += 1
            map_val = f'{i_type}_{n_occur}-{i_type}'

        mapping[i] = map_val
    return mapping


l1 = ["1-int", "2-double", "1-string", "5-list", "5-int"]
l2 = ["3-string", "1-int", "1-double", "5-double", "5-string"]

l1_mapping = process_type_list(l1)
l2_mapping = process_type_list(l2)
```

Additionally, **Python does not have a `double` type**.  C doubles are implemented as Python `float`s (or [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) if you need fine control over the precision)